# Trying to understand the types produced by monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

The [docs for `Control.Monad.Trans.Error`](http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/packages/transformers-0.2.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html) provide this example of combining two monads:

```
type ErrorWithIO e a = ErrorT e IO a
==> ErrorT (IO (Either e a))
```

I find this counterintuitive:  even though `ErrorT` is supposedly *wrapping* `IO`, it looks like the error information has been injected *into* the IO action's result type.  I would've expected it to be

```
==> ErrorT (Either e (IO a))
```

based on the usual meaning of the word "wrap".

To make matters more confusing, `StateT` does some of each:

```
type MyError e = ErrorT e Identity  -- (see footnote)
type StateWithError s e a = StateT s (MyError e) a
==> StateT (s -> ErrorT (Either e (a, s)))
```

The state type `s` has been injected into the `Either`'s `Right` side, but the whole `Either` has also been wrapped in a function.

To make matters even *more* confusing, if the monads are combined the other way around:

```
type ErrorWithState e s a = ErrorT e (State s) a
==> ErrorT (StateT (s -> (Either e a, s)))
```

the "outside" is still a function; it doesn't produce something like `Either e (s -> (a, s))`, where the state function is nested within the error type.

I'm sure there's some underlying logical consistency to all this, but I don't quite see it.  Consequently I find it difficult to think about what it means to combine one monad with another, even when I have no trouble understanding what each monad means individually.

Can someone enlighten me?

---

(**Footnote:** I'm composing `ErrorT` with `Identity` so that `StateWithError` and `ErrorWithState` are consistent with each other, for illustrative purposes.  Normally I'd just use `StateWithError s e a = StateT s (Either e) a` and forego the `ErrorT` layer.

Comment: This puzzles me a lot too. From the haskell wiki book: "In general, there is no magic formula to create a transformer version of a monad" (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers). For the specific case of wrapping ErrorT around IO, the reason the Either has to be on the inside is that whether it's a Left or a Right has to (in order to be useful) be capable of depending on the result of an IO action, and everything that depends on the result of an IO action has to be *inside* the IO monad.

Comment: You can usually come up with heuristic arguments like these (like ReaderT has to be "outside" so the thing can actually *depend* on the value -- I'm guessing similar reason for StateT). If there's a general rule I don't know it.

Comment: @Owen: You pretty much have the only general rule already. The transformer's function arguments go on the outside, everything else goes on the inside. This covers all the standard transformers, I think, even `ContT`. Arguably recursion should be interleaved, but the `ListT` in `transformers` doesn't do this.

Comment: I suggest you examine the source code for the `ErrorT` instance of the `Monad` type class.  It's very straightforward and you'll see exactly why one might want to describe it as *wrapping*.  You may also want to check out the source for `lift` too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I find this counterintuitive: even though ErrorT is supposedly wrapping IO, it looks like the error information has been injected into the IO action's result type.

Monad transformers aren't in general "wrapping" the monad they're applied to, at least not in any obvious sense. Thinking of it as "wrapping" would imply *functor composition* to my mind, which is specifically what's not going on here.

To illustrate, functor composition for `State s` and `Maybe`, with definitions expanded, would look like this:

```
newtype StateMaybe s a = StateMaybe (s -> (Maybe a, s))    -- == State s (Maybe a)
newtype MaybeState s a = MaybeState (Maybe (s -> (a, s)))  -- == Maybe (State s a)
```

Note that in the first case, `State` behaves normally, and `Nothing` doesn't impact the state value; in the second case, we either have a plain `State` function or nothing at all. In neither case do the characteristic behaviors of the two monads actually *combine*. This shouldn't be surprising since, after all, these are the same as what you'd get by simply having values using one monad as regular values used within the other.

Compare this to `StateT s Maybe`:

```
newtype StateTMaybe s a = StateTMaybe (s -> Maybe (a, s))
```

In this case, the two are woven together; things proceed in the normal manner for `State`, unless we hit a `Nothing`, in which case the computation is aborted. This is fundamentally different from the above cases, which is why *monad transformers* even exist in the first place--composing them naively doesn't require any special machinery, because they operate independently of each other.

---

As far as making sense of which one is on the "outside", it might help to think of the "outer" transformer as being the one whose behavior takes "priority", in some sense, when dealing with values in the monad, while the "inner" monad only sees business as usual. Note that this is why `IO` is always innermost--it doesn't let anything else get up in its business, whereas a hypothetical `IOT` transformer would be forced to allow the wrapped monad to pull all kinds of shenanigans, like duplicating or discarding the `RealWorld` token.

- `StateT` and `ReaderT` both put the "inner" monad around the result of the function; you have to provide a state value or environment before getting at the transformed monad.
- `MaybeT` and `ErrorT` both slip themselves *inside* the transformed monad, ensuring that it can behave in the usual manner except that a value that might not be present.
- `Writer` is completely passive and just attaches itself to the values in the monad, since it doesn't impact behavior at all.
- `ContT` keeps things to itself, putting off dealing with the transformed monad altogether by only wrapping the *result* type.

That's a bit hand-wavy, but eh, monad transformers are kind of ad-hoc and confusing to begin with, alas. I don't know if there's any tidy theoretical justification for the particular choices made, other than the fact that they *work*, and do what you'd usually want the combination (not composition) of the two monads to do.

> Consequently I find it difficult to think about what it means to combine one monad with another, even when I have no trouble understanding what each monad means individually.

Yeah, this sounds like about what to expect, I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess it stands to reason that since different monads do completely different things, their transformers do completely different things too.

Answer (score 5):

Consider what would happen, if ErrorT were defined the way you would imagine it.  How would you encode an IO action, which fails?  With `Either e (IO a)` you cannot give a `Left` value, when the action fails, because at the time you reach the action it's already clear that it's a `Right` value – otherwise it wouldn't be an action.

With `IO (Either e a)` however this isn't the case.  The whole thing is an IO action now and can return a `Left` value to indicate error.  As others noted, don't think of monad transformers as wrappers.  Rather think of them as functions.  They take a monad and turn it into another monad.  They *transform* monads.

Comment: That's what sparked the question, actually:  I wanted an IO action that could fail, and I thought I couldn't accomplish that with `ErrorT`, until I discovered that `ErrorT` actually does the opposite of what I assumed it would.  But I don't see what makes this way the "right" way and the other way the "wrong" way — what if I *did* want a pure computation that could fail to produce an IO action?

Comment: @Wyzard: Then you'd just have a pure computation in an `ErrorT e Identity` monad, which happens to produce a value of type `IO a`. There's no transforming happening there, just using the two monads separately.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I just realized that myself.  In that case I could just write an ordinary pure function that returns `Either e (IO a)`.